# Will BroadcastReceivers fire if the app is completely shut off?

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, android-service

My app schedules Alarms using AlarmManager and a BroadcastReceiver class.

It works if the app is running or backgrounded, but if it is completely killed, it seems the event is not fired.

The receiver calls an IntentService which calls Maps REST API with some parameters and then displays the formatted output in a notification. The service does this without using AsyncTask as it is already a background thread.

Also, is there a good way to check if the Receiver or Service is invoked if the application is not in Debug?

Comment: How did you register the receiver ?

Comment: It is in the manifest. I'm not sure which part is breaking to be honest whether it's the receiver, data download, intent service, or notifications logic. It works sometimes but other times not.. guess need to create a logger that write to DB and see which logic is actually fired.

Answer (score 2):

If your `BroadcastReceiver` must receive intents even when app is killed, you should register to desired intents via `AndroidManifest.xml`.

This way, the `BroadcastReceiver` will be indepedent from your app life cicle.

This way, your `BroadcastReceiver` will be notified automatically by Android as soon as the desired intent was broadcasted by some app

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest>
    ...

    <application>
        ....
        <receiver android:name=".MyCustomBroadcastReceiver">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.example.mytestapp.MY_CUSTOM_INTENT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

**MyCustomBroadcastReceiver.java**

```
public class MyCustomBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        if(intent != null) {
            String action = intent.getAction();
            if(action != null) {
                if(action.equals("com.example.mytestapp.MY_CUSTOM_INTENT")) {
                    // DO YOUR STUFF
                } 
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Creating the Alarm Intent**

Then, when creating your alarm manager, use the code below:

```
Intent intentForAlarmManager = new Intent("com.example.mytestapp.MY_CUSTOM_INTENT");

PendingIntent.getBroadcast(/* CONTEXT */, /* ID */ , intentForAlarmManager, /* FLAGS */));
```